# How do I load firebase data using vue and vuefire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I'm not understanding something about getting firebase data into vue... I'm happy to delete the question or quit my job as a programmer once I get an answer ;)

I get that the data is async, so vue is trying to render the component before the data has been received. But, I don't see how to make it wait. Examples would be greatly appreciated. I've tried reading the docs, but I'm just not understanding.

It's a tiny tiny app that displays our company's parking lot and saves the user's tap (car) location to firebase (we're tired of forgetting where we parked). Grateful for any help!

Oh, and I'm using set() because only one car location needs to be saved at a time, so it's ok that the data is overwritten each time the user taps a new place on the screen.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span id="marker" class="fas fa-times" :style="{ left: leftCoord, top: topCoord }"></span>
    <img @click="saveCoordinates($event)" src="./assets/parking-lot.jpg">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
  apiKey: 'MY-API-KEY',
  authDomain: 'MY-APP.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://MY-APP.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'MY-APP',
  storageBucket: 'MY-APP.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '1234567890'
}
const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)

const db = app.database()
const locationRef = db.ref('location')

export default {
  name: 'app',
  firebase: {
    location: locationRef
  },
  mounted () {
    this.leftCoord = this.location.leftCoord
    this.topCoord = this.location.topCoord
  },
  data () {
    return {
      leftCoord: '',
      topCoord: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveCoordinates: function (clickEvent) {
      const coordinates = {
        leftCoord: clickEvent.layerX,
        topCoord: clickEvent.layerY
      }
      this.location.set(coordinates)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is something I don't fully understand: you say that "vue is trying to render the component before the data has been received" but in the code you shared there is nowhere a call to **read** the database, just a button that fires a **write**. Could you clarify? What is the exact problem?

Comment: In the mounted hook, I'm trying to set the left and top coordinates for the marker, using the reference from the firebase db, and then apply those changes with the style binding in the marker in the template. The initial error I'm receiving is that .set() is not a function.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks for pointing that! In the mounted hook what do you get if you do `console.log(this.location)` ?

Comment: And what if you do `this.leftCoord = locationRef.leftCoord`

Comment: the log statement yields an empty array and removing 'this' throws 'TypeError: this.location.set is not a function'

Comment: Hold on, I am looking for a solution

Comment: Thanks! This has stumped my team for a couple days now. We're all Angular devs exploring using vue for an upcoming project.

Comment: Is `location` array or object in your firebase?

Comment: location is an object with leftCoord and topCoord props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a second answer, which is not based anymore on the `mounted` hook but on the callback function of the object binding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuefire/dist/vuefire.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="app">

    <span id="marker" class="fas fa-times" :style="{ left: leftCoord, top: topCoord }"></span>
    <img @click="saveCoordinates($event)" src="./assets/parking-lot.jpg">

</div>

<script>

    var config = {
        apiKey: ".........",
        authDomain: ".........",
        databaseURL: ".........",
        projectId: ".........",
        storageBucket: "........."
    };


    /* global Vue, firebase */
    var db = firebase.initializeApp(config).database()
    var todosRef = db.ref('todos')

    const locationRef = db.ref('location')

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        name: 'app',
        firebase: {
            location: {
                source: locationRef,
                asObject: true,
                readyCallback: function () {
                    this.leftCoord = this.location.leftCoord
                    this.topCoord = this.location.topCoord
                }
            }

        },
        data() {
            return {
                leftCoord: '',
                topCoord: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            saveCoordinates: function (clickEvent) {
                console.log(clickEvent.layerX)
                const coordinates = {
                    leftCoord: clickEvent.layerX,
                    topCoord: clickEvent.layerY
                }
                locationRef.set(coordinates)
            }
        }
    })


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's really fantastic. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuefire/dist/vuefire.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="app">

    <span id="marker" class="fas fa-times" :style="{ left: leftCoord, top: topCoord }"></span>
    <img @click="saveCoordinates($event)" src="./assets/parking-lot.jpg">

    <img @click="readCoords" src="./assets/parking-lot.jpg">

</div>

<script>

    var config = {
        apiKey: ".........",
        authDomain: ".........",
        databaseURL: ".........",
        projectId: ".........",
        storageBucket: "........."
    };


    /* global Vue, firebase */
    var db = firebase.initializeApp(config).database()
    var todosRef = db.ref('todos')

    const locationRef = db.ref('location')

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        name: 'app',
        firebase: {
            location: {
                source: locationRef,
                asObject: true
            }

        },
        mounted() {

            locationRef.once('value', snapshot => {
                this.leftCoord = this.location.leftCoord
                this.topCoord = this.location.topCoord
            })

        },
        data() {
            return {
                leftCoord: '',
                topCoord: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            saveCoordinates: function (clickEvent) {
                console.log(clickEvent.layerX)
                const coordinates = {
                    leftCoord: clickEvent.layerX,
                    topCoord: clickEvent.layerY
                }
                locationRef.set(coordinates)
            },

            readCoords: function (clickEvent) {
                console.log(this.location.leftCoord);
                console.log(this.location.topCoord);
            }
        }
    })


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Apparently there is no "native" way in vuefire to wait into a mounted hook that the data is loaded, see https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/69

I've added a second image link with a new function `readCoords` just for testing purpose.

---

Note that you could also do in the mounted hook

```
locationRef.once('value', snapshot => {
    this.leftCoord = snapshot.val().leftCoord
    this.topCoord = snapshot.val().topCoord
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome (I've learnt something too :-), which makes SO so good)

Answer (score 1):

If location is an object, you need to bind like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  firebase: {
    location: {
      source: db.ref('location'),
      asObject: true,
      readyCallback: function () {}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.leftCoord = this.location.leftCoord
    this.topCoord = this.location.topCoord
  },
  data () {
    return {
      leftCoord: '',
      topCoord: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveCoordinates: function (clickEvent) {
      const coordinates = {
        leftCoord: clickEvent.layerX,
        topCoord: clickEvent.layerY
      }
      this.$firebaseRefs.location.set(coordinates)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that when setting, we need to use `this.$firebaseRefs.location.set(coordinates)`

Document https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire